# Installing Zend Framework After Xampp

Tags: windows, zend-framework, xampp

I am running Windows 7 and am using Xampp.  I would like to install the Zend framework for PHP, but I am having difficulties understanding how to install it.  I have used the Zend framework before, but it was already installed on the Linux system I was working on.

I am reading through the Zend documentation here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html

I am having trouble with updating the includes_path portion.  My original include path was `include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR"`, but I updated it to `include_path = ".;C:\Zend"`.

I then followed the directions for creating a new project by opening the command line tool and running `% C:\Zend\bin\zf.sh create project testproject` in the desired directory.  I get the following error message: `'%' is not recognized as an internal or external command, or a batch file`.

Some help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`C:\Zend\bin\zf.sh` is for linux, you need `C:\Zend\bin\zf.bat` I dont even know how you could run it

To setup ZF you just need to add `C:\Zend\library` in your `include_path`

To fix *PHP not found* you need to add `;C:\xampp\php\` to the environment variable "Path" from

Click `Start`, Right Click on `Computer` then click `Properties`

Then Advanced System settings>Advanced Tab/Environment Variables>System variables>Path/Edit...

[image]

Then append to the end `;C:\xampp\php`

You should also append `;C:\Zend\bin` for easy access to `zf.bat` [2]

Then to create project do not use `cd C:\Zend\bin`!! because your project will be created into that directory. Use the full path `C:\Zend\bin\zf create project quickstart`

or if you did step [2], simply go to your `htdocs` (with `cd your_htdocs_path`) or whatever you set in apache for web root and execute `zf create projext quickstart`

you also might need to setup a virtual host "quickstart" in apache and probably new line in windows  `hosts` file: `127.0.0.1 quickstart` because ZF is designed mainly for virtual hosts

Answer (score 1):

you can install the zend framework using PEAR

```
pear channel-discover zend.googlecode.com/svn
pear install zend/zend
```

If you don't know where is your PEAR executable, run a file search for "pear", or "pear.exe".

After that, check out the section called "Setting up the CLI tool on Windows" in http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tool.framework.clitool.html. It will help you set up a easy access to the zf command line tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can also go to your zendFrame work where you have extracted it and then go to bin folder (in my case “C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendFramework\bin”) where you can find zf.bat .
Edit it with any editer and go to

```
“SET PHP_BIN=php.exe ”
```

and set it to

```
“SET PHP_BIN=C:\xampp\php\php.exe”
```

and it worked for me…

Answer (score 0):

Look's like your trying to run a shell script on cmd, not going to work, try this:

**Start** *>* **Run** *>* **cmd** [enter]

```
> cd  C:\path\to\html\docs
> C:\Zend\bin\zf create project quickstart
```

and do not place the `>` marker, just the `cd ..` and `zf ..`

Comment: OK, looks like it's actually trying to run something, but I keep getting the error "php.exe" is not recognized as internal or external command....

Comment: don't do that it will create your project in `C:\Zend\bin\` you don't want that

Answer (score -1):

Add the path to the php interpreter to the %PATH% environment variable:
control panel => system => Advanced system settings => Environment Variables... => System Variables =>  => append `;C:\xampp\php`

Comment: Which the name of the ;C:\xampp\php    should be then?